# Ajax in JQuery not Returning Correct Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to return unique results in the inner scope of my Ajax request.

```
var id = pooInLoo['timeline'][e][i]['_id']; 
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/'+id+'/lovequantity',
    type: 'GET',
        success: function(loveCount) {
            console.log('inside: ' +id);
            $('#'+id).append(loveCount);
        }
    });
```

The console.log only returns one result inside that Ajax request. In reality, there's 3 unique IDs that should be logged.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/timeline/profile',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(pooInLoo) {
                for(var e = 0; e < pooInLoo['timeline'].length; e++) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < pooInLoo['timeline'][e].length; i++) {
                        var id = pooInLoo['timeline'][e][i]['_id']; 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/api/'+id+'/lovequantity',
                            type: 'GET',
                            success: function(loveCount) {
                                console.log('inside: ' +id);
                                $('#'+id).append(loveCount);
                            }
                        });
                        console.log('outside: ' +id);
                        $('#timelineWrapper').append('<div class="timeline"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12"> <div id="author"> <div id="profilePhoto"> <img src="" /> </div> <div id="name"> <h6> @'+pooInLoo['timeline'][e][i]['username']+'</h6> </div> </div> <hr> <div id="bookData"> <div id="bookCover"> </div> <div id="bookDetails"> <h4> '+pooInLoo['timeline'][e][i]['title']+' </h4> <h5> '+pooInLoo['timeline'][e][i]['author']+' </h5> <h6 id="'+pooInLoo['timeline'][e][i]['_id']+'"> <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></h6> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I have segregated the console.log from the inner-scope 'inside' with the outer-scope 'outside'.

The outer scope returns the correct 3 different results, while the inner scope only returns one result 3 times.

```
outside: 5b90e133ef88180357689b54 
outside: 5b9383c923f0a302693b8d3e
outside: 5b93840623f0a302693b8d40 
inside: 5b93840623f0a302693b8d40 x3
```

What can I do to get the inner scope returning 3 different IDs?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you saying the AJAX response is not as you'd like? If so, that's down to the web service you're calling. Or do you mean you're having trouble parsing/accessing it?

Comment: The name `callback` for the first parameter of the `success` handler is wrong. A callback is a function, but the `success` handler receives the response from the server (most likely _data_) which won't be a function at all.

Comment: Why does it matter what the name of a variable is called? 

@Utkanos having trouble accessing it in that scope.

Comment: To make the code self-explanatory. If I see a variable called `callback` I assume that it stores a function which will be called later in the workflow and not that it contains the parsed response of a GET request.

Comment: Please provide a properly detailed explanation of the problem

Comment: @charlietfl read the original post.

Comment: I did and just like Utkanos mentioned it is not at all clear what you are asking or what the specific problem is. Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Note that if the problem was clear you probably would have had several suggestions/ answers by now

Comment: @charlieftl   how about now?

Comment: and @Utkanos now?

Comment: Can you post the server response for both requests? Also, I can only imagine what sort of thing you're building that requires variables called `pooInLoo` and `loveCount`... :)

Answer (score 0):

The id variable in the 'inside' scope is simply a reference to the id in the 'outside' scope. Since 'inside' is a callback function, it is called asynchronously and when it is called, id is pretty much set to the last id that was iterated in the nested for-loop, which is probably the reason why you get 3 identical ids logged from the inner scope. I think you might be able to solve the problem by copying the id from the outer scope into the callback function's scope instead of referencing.